# What happens when you assign a value of greater than 1 to a bit in a register?

Tags: bit, bit-shift, cpu-registers

What happens if I set a single bit to a value greater than 1 like below?

```
CANCDMOB = ( 1 << CONMOB1) | ( 1 << IDE ) | ( 8 << DLC0);
```

Will the DLC0 bit just be set to 1 or will it affect the next bits in the register aswell?
DLC0 is the LSB of an 8-bit register.

Comment: I absolutely do not understand your question. You do NOT assign a bit in a register. Indeed, there is no way to do it directly in most common architectures. You compute an integer by shifting and or-ing some bits and you assign it globally to the variable CANCDMOB (or to the register that holds it). And DLC0 is a right-hand symbol and can not be modified by this assignment. Can you give some precisions on your problem and/or the specific architecture you are considering.

Comment: The DLC0 has a value defined as 0. So i suppose that I am inserting an "8" in the 0th bit of the CANDCMOB register. My question is if this gets converted to a 1 in the register since it only uses 1s and 0s?

Comment: NO. 1<<0 is 1 shifted left 0 times and is just a one. And you cannot "insert an 8 in the 0th bit", as 8 requires 4 bits to be coded.

Comment: Okay, will the above operation then cause the last four bits of the register to be "1000" since I am shifting 8 (0b1000) 0 times?

Comment: You are true that  8<<0=1000b. But if your registers are 32 bits wide, you write all the 32 bits to it. So, all the bits will be modified (and not only the 4 LSB). And the value of the 4 LSB depends on the value of CONMOD1 and IDE. For instance, if both are 0, You OR with 1<<0 and the result is 000...001001b